# How to create the function currying more dynamic? (JAVA SCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, function, currying

The question was to create a function that returns function using currying or something like that.

And then the teacher asked us to make it more dynamic.
What if there were 'n' number of arguments passed on to the function like.

```
console.log(xx()()()()()()...n times);
```

up to n times but we don't know the value of 'n'.

How to create this?

```
 function xx (x){
    return  (y) => {
        return (z) => {
           return ()=>{
               return x*y*z;

           }
        }
    }
}
console.log(xx(2) (3) (4) );
```

This will only return the value up to 4 times.

Is there a way to input

```
console.log (xx(2)(3)(4)(5)(6));
```

And it also check if it is a empty argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `X`, when called with an argument `a`, should return another function that accepts another argument, `b`, applies the operation to `a` and `b` and invokes the original function with the result, thus repeating the whole thing:

```js
function X(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return b ? X(a + b) : a
    }
}

//

console.log(
    X(1)(2)(3)(4)()
)
```

Comment: This handles `0` incorrectly: `X(1)(2)(3)(4)(0)(5)() // TypeError: ... is not a function`.

Comment: @InSync: the fix is left to the reader ;)

Comment: Below works for me:
function X(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return b>=0 ? X(a + b) : a
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, all your inner functions you return (*except the last one*) are the same. You just create a closure over their argument and then return another function that does the same thing.

```js
function xx(x) {
  // if the initial call does not have a value 
  // return undefined
  if (x === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  // if there is a value in the initial call
  // then store it in a list 
  const numbers = [x];

  // return a function (named inner in this scenario) that handles the subsequent calls
  return function inner(y) {
    // if a subsequent call provides a value
    // add it to the list of numbers
    // and return the inner function for handling the
    // next calls
    if (y !== undefined) {
      numbers.push(y);
      return inner;
    }
    // if a value was not provided (this is the last call)
    // then do the calculations and return the result
    let total = 1;
    numbers.forEach(function(number) {
      total = total * number;
    });
    return total;
  }
}


console.log(xx(2)(3)());
console.log(xx(2)(3)(4)());
console.log(xx(2)(3)(4)(5)());
```